# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fyers_api'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running the below code to connect fyers API:

```
from fyers_api import accessToken
from fyers_api import fyersModel

app_id = "app_id"
app_secret = "secret_id"
app_session = accessToken.SessionModel(app_id, app_secret)
response = app_session.auth()
```

But still getting error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fyers_api'
```

Please help to resolve issue. I did install fyers_api module. `pip install fyers_api`

Comment: Please have a look at the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Python 3 (because `ModuleNotFoundError` is specific to Python 3), you should be using `pip3` instead of `pip` to install packages:

```
pip3 install fyers_api
```

`pip install fyers_api` will install it for Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

Download fyers api package from [here](https://pypi.org/project/fyers-api/#files)

For Anaconda-3 run below command from the anaconda prompt.

```
pip install <path to the downloaded package>
```